# MTP connection with PC required for android but is it device independent?

Tags: android, windows

I want to write a program on windows which transfers music to android via MTP.
The real device I have is HTC desire(froyo) and when I connect this via a USB cable to PC, it shows up as a removable storage and not as a Windows Portable Device ..

only ICS seems to support MTP but I do not have it. I was looking if I could connect Android Emulator with ICS to my host machine via some sort of emulated USB connection. But this not supported in android emulator.

I need some tip or suggestions as to how can I setup the environment to program for it.

I have another device (a creative media player) which shows up as Windows portable device. 
If this protocol is device independent can I write my program for my "Creative media player" and expect that it would theoretically work with android ?

Thanks,